# Add elements to array that is an object property

Tags: php, arrays, object, properties

Let's say I have these classes:

```
abstract class AbstractEntity {
    function __construct($args = array()) {
        foreach ($args as $property => $value) {
            $this->{$property} = $value;
        }
    }

    public function __get( $property ) {
        if( isset( $this->{$property} ) ) {
            return $this->{$property};
        } else {
           throw new \Exception( 'Porperty ' . $property . ' not found!' );
        }
    }
    public function __set($property, $value) {
        if( isset( $this->{$property} ) ) {
            $this->{$property} = $value;
        } else {
            throw new \Exception( 'Porperty ' . $property . ' not found!' );
        }
    }
}

class Person extends AbstractEntity {
    protected $name;
}

class Group extends AbstractEntity  {
    protected $people; // array of Person
}
```

Now I want to populate the `$people` property with `Person` objects in a loop, like:

```
$group = new Group( array( 'people' => array() ) );

foreach ( get_people_data() as $person_data ) {
    $group->people[] = new Person( $person_data['name'] );
}
```

But this doesn't work, I get an error:

```
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property Group::$people has no effect in ...
```

I know I can use a temp array, fill it with `Person` objects and then assign it to the `$people` property, but I kind of don't like it... so, is there any other solution?

Comment: Post more of `class Group`.  Does it implement a magic `__get()`? It should be implicit, but if you declare `public $people = array();` does anything change? ( I don't expect it to)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, see edited code, I tried to summarize but I got rid of important bits...

Comment: Read about [property visibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). You are declaring none, but the properties should be `public`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, mine are actually protected, is it a good practice to make them public? I've always been told it's not... or that happens nly in Java??

Comment: Well if they are `protected`, you cannot access them outside the class (such as in your loop) and that's the source of your problem. If you need to append to `$group->people[]` outside the class, they need to be public

Comment: You can keep them `protected`, but you would need to write a method on `Group` for appending to people like `public function addPerson($name)`

Comment: Why don't you use a setter?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, but I have a magic __get which allows me to access the properties like that, doesn't it? (I'm new to PHP from Java sorry)

Comment: Your `__set()` could be modified to test if the property is an array and append to it, otherwise set it as you are already doing.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, ok that's the closest to what I'm looking for, but the problem is that, within the loop, I have to use `$group->people = new Person( $person_data['name'] );` (without the brackets `[]`), which is a bit confusing...

Comment: @MikO Indeed, that is confusing. I've never tried it so I wasn't sure how it would behave. A dedicated setter like `addPerson()` is much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I added a function to my `AbstractEntity` class that allows to add a `$value` to a `$property` of the class, which must be an `array`:

```
public function append_to( $property, $value ) {

    // Check that $property exists on the object and is an array
    if( isset( $this->{$property} ) && is_array( $this->{$property} ) ) {

        $this->{$property}[] = $value;

    } else {

        throw new \Exception( 'Porperty ' . $property . ' not found or is not array!' );
    }
}
```

These has some benefits (in my opinion) than other approaches commented here:

1. I don't need to make any field `public`.
2. I don't have to create a function like `addPerson()`, so I can keep all the classes extending `AbstractEntity` as a simple bunch of properties without ANY function.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make $people property public. It works in my case.

```
[...]
public $people = array(); // array of Person
[...]

$group->people[] = new Person( 1);
$group->people[] = new Person( 2);
```

Comment: Then use setters/getters.

Or method like addPerson();

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems kind of incomplete and this is what my assumption and see how it goes...

```
<?php

class Person {
    public $name;
    function __construct($n)
    {
        $this->name=$n;
    }
}

class Group {
public $people = array(); // array of Person
}

$arr = [0=>['name'=>'John'],1=>['name'=>'Jack'],2=>['name'=>'Jill']];
$group = new Group();
foreach ($arr as $person_data ) {
    $group->people[] = new Person( $person_data['name'] );
}
print_r($group->people);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Person Object
        (
            [name] => John
        )

    [1] => Person Object
        (
            [name] => Jack
        )

    [2] => Person Object
        (
            [name] => Jill
        )

)
```

Comment: You know `protected` and `private` members cannot be accessed outside of the class right ?

Comment: Well, I'd rather say that `protected` and `private` properties cannot be accesed outside the class *directly*, but only with getter and setter methods, like those I have in my `AbstractEntity` class, which `Group` and `Person` inherit from... right?